# Asp.net Postback issue

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have Department Dropdown on change of this I made jquery-ajax request to get the Department Details.

I'll be binding this result to a Div.

that works well till here.

When I click an asp.net button or any server side control after post back the div element is emptied.

How can I get the previous result in the div element.

Success function for Ajax call goes like below:

```
 function OnSuccess(response) {
        var List = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
        DeptDetails = "";
        $.each(List, function () {
            DeptDetails = "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='grid' border='0' width='94%'>";
            DeptDetails = DeptDetails + "<tr><td align='right' style='padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 3px;'>Store Name:</td><td align='left' style='padding-left:3px;padding-top:3px;'>" + this["DeptName"] + "</td></tr>";
            DeptDetails = DeptDetails + "<tr><td align='right' style='padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 3px;'>Address:</td><td align='left' style='padding-left:3px;padding-top:3px;'>" + this["Address"] + "</td></tr>";
            DeptDetails = DeptDetails + "<tr><td align='right' style='padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 3px;'>Zone:</td><td align='left' style='padding-left:3px;padding-top:3px;'>" + this["ZoneName"] + "</td></tr>";
            DeptDetails = DeptDetails + "<tr><td align='right' style='padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 3px;'>Zone Manager:</td><td align='left' style='padding-left:3px;padding-top:3px;'>" + this["ZoneManager"] + "</td></tr></table>";
            $('div[id*="divDeptDetails"]').html(DeptDetails);

        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance.It is urgent guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   // check here if the drop down has a selected item different than the default one

   // make the same ajax call you are doing on the drop down
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Anand, you need to persist the data by adding the data to the viewstate or by sending it along with a hidden input.

Comment: working fine with hidden field.But there is an issue like "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client " when navigating to a different page.Hidden field contains the the table markup posted above

Comment: Easy fixable by altering the markup (.aspx) of your page by setting ValidateRequest="false" in the header.

Comment: I hope you do realize the potential security threat this opens up since you could inject any markup into this field.

Comment: I have set the ValidateRequest=false in the page where hidden field is present and is ok.But I'm navigating to a different page it is giving the same error.

Comment: Add it for every page you post to, or escape the data you post like fox mentioned.